# Where can I get Hibernate Annotations from?

Tags: hibernate

I have just started reading a Hibernate book and it says go to Hibenrate.org and download both HibernateCore and Hibernate Annotations ..well I am at the website and cannot find Hibernate Annotations to download it... is it something that its name is changed after the book I am using is published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download it from there, for example: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.5.6-Final/

But AFAIR in latest versions of Hibernate it become part of hibernate-core JAR.